# What is the appropriate optimization method (algorithm) to solve such problems (Linear mixed-integer)?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have this optimization problem:
[image: optimization problem]

In this problem, C_{i,k} is a matrix of binary values (i.e., 0 or 1) and w_i is a vector of integers, p_f is a probability,  and \epsilon is a constant. 
I understand that the problem is a linear mixed-integer problem. But I'm confused about the method or algorithm I should use to solve the problem, and how can I go further by doing convexity analysis. 
Your inputs are appreciated. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: My advice: just try to solve as a MIP by using a MIP solver (and possible a modeling tool). If the problem is large, get a good MIP solver. Note that linear models are convex already (I don't know what convexity analysis is in this respect).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). This problem can be solved using either dynamic programming or branch-and-bound algorithm. For branch and bound, you could select any variable z_k, solve two subproblems with z_k equals to either 0 or 1. Each subproblem has the exact structure as the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please suggest any modeling reference for the Knapsack problem using any one of the tow suggested algorithms.

Comment: My first choice for this problem would be to use an integer programming solver, such as Gurobi/Mosek, etc. If instead you don't want to call a solver, you could try either dynamic programming or branch and bound.
If you know the greatest common divisor of log(p_f^k) for all k, then you could use the dynamic programming approach. Here is a  tutorial on dynamic programming http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5MC10/Solutions/knapsack.pdf, the capacity "W" in this tutorial is ln(1-ε) in your formulation.

Comment: You could also try the branch-and-bound algorithm for this problem. Here is a tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-0-1-knapsack-using-branch-and-bound/. branch-and-bound is more general than dynamic programming, as it doesn't require knowing the greatest common divisor of log(p_f^k).

Comment: BTW, the commercial solvers (Mosek/Gurobi) typically uses an advanced version of branch-and-bound algorithm, called branch-and-cut, namely branch-and-bound together with a technique called cutting planes. https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Branch_and_cut